# AngularJS $http is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to with AngularJS. When I'm calling `$http.get` I get a `$http is not defined` error.

This is the content of my Module:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/view1',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'View1.html'
        }).
        when('/view2',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'View2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
});

demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', function () {

    var factory = {};
    factory.getAnnounces = function ($http) {
        $http.post("http://localhost:57034/Announce/GetAllAnnounces")
           .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               return data;
           }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               return status;
           });
           };
    return factory;
});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope,simpleFactory) {

    $scope.announces = [];
    init();
    function init()
    {
        $scope.announces= simpleFactory.getAnnounces();
    }

});
```

What am I missing here? Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to review your code as follows:

```
demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    return {
        getAnnounces: function () {
            $http.post("http://localhost:57034/Announce/GetAllAnnounces")
               .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   return data;
               }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   return status;
               });
        }
    };

}]);
```

There's no need to pass the `$http` variable in the `getAnnounces` method definition, because it is defined already in the scope of the factory function.

I am using parameter aliasing for AngularJS in order to avoid issues with minifiers, see '**A note on minification**' on the [AngularJS web site](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Note anyway that `$http.post.success` and `$http.post.error` are **asynchronous** and you won't be able to get the data unless you're using promises (`$q`), see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q). Therefore you could change the code this way:

```
demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    return {
        getAnnounces: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post("http://localhost:57034/Announce/GetAllAnnounces")
               .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   deferred.resolve(data);
               }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   deferred.reject(data);
               });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

}]);
```

And in the `SimpleController`:

```
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', ['simpleFactory', '$scope', function (simpleFactory, $scope) {

    $scope.announces = []; 

    simpleFactory.getAnnounces()
        .then(function(data) {
            // call was successful
            $scope.announces = data;
        }, function(data) {
            // call returned an error
            $scope.announces = data;
        });

}]);
```