# Angular JS bind results from api to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi ya'll I am trying to take this data that is returned from an api:

```
[{"Language":{"Id":1,"Name":"English"},"Occupations":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Banquet Server"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Bar Tender"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Catering Manager"}]
```

and bind it to a dropdown menu using angular JS:

```
$scope.industry = [];

    $http.get('/industrygroup?languageid=1')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.industry = result.data;
        });
```

and here is the HTML layout

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:25% !important; margin-bottom:20px;" ng-model="industry">
```

but my dropdown menu appears blank....what I am trying to do is display each name from the json above.....anyone have any suggestions? Here is some more of angular JS code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('WizardController', function($scope){

    $scope.industry = [];

    $http.get('/industrygroup?languageid=1')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.industry = result.data;
        });

  $scope.user = {
    agree: null
  };

});
```

`$scope.user` is what I use to collect data from input fields.

Comment: Please show what items you want to appear in the drop down. Also `ng-model` on a select tag is the selected item, while `ng-options` is used to define the available items.

Comment: what I am trying to do is display each Name from the json

Comment: which names? "Language/Occupations" or "English" or "Banquet Server/Bar Tender"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need

*.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('WizardController', function($scope){

    $scope.industry = [];

    $http.get('/industrygroup?languageid=1')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.industry = result.data;
        });

  $scope.user = {
    agree: null
  };
  $scope.selected = null;

});
```

*.html

```
<select data-ng-options="p.Name for p in industry[0].Occupations" data-ng-model="selected">
</select>
```

**Also**

if your json contains many objects like this:

```
[{
    "Language": {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "English"
    },
    "Occupations": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Banquet Server"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Bar Tender"
    }, {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Catering Manager"
    }]
  } ,
  {
    "Language": {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "English2"
    },
    "Occupations": [{
      "Id": 4,
      "Name": "Banquet Server 2"
    }, {
      "Id": 5,
      "Name": "Bar Tender 2"
    }, {
      "Id": 6,
      "Name": "Catering Manager 2"
    }]
  }, ...];
```

and you want **all the Occupations names** you can do it:

*.js

```
$scope.Options = function()
{
   var data =[];

   for(var i = 0;i < $scope.industry.length;i++)
       for(var j = 0;j < $scope.industry[i].Occupations.length;j++)
           data.push($scope.industry[i].Occupations[j].Name);

    return data;
}
```

*.html

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="op in Options()">{{op}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `ng-options` requires `ng-model`, so this won't work as presented. It also doesn't match the structure of the JSON the OP presented.

Comment: I used ng-options="p.Occupations.name for p in industry" and ng-model="user.industry" user.industry is used for saving the value of the dropdown menu

Comment: Actually this won't work either, as there is no `Occupations.name` property in the JSON. I think what they may want is to have the occupation names enumerated, so maybe something like `<select ng-options="p.name for p in industry[0].Occupations">`, but they really have to clarify to say for sure

Comment: yes @MarcKline it is not 100% clear, edit my answer if you want

Comment: ahhh now im getting an error saying $http is not defined.

Comment: that's a differente problem man, try `myApp.controller('WizardController', function($scope, $http){`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759120/angularjs-referenceerror-http-is-not-defined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882705/angularjs-http-is-not-defined

Answer (score 2):

Please review this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ibu2RZZipgifKriSe5l?p=preview)

The markup will need to look like this:

```
<select ng-model="occupation" ng-options="occ.Name for occ in industry[0].Occupations"></select>
```

- `industry` is an array so you'll need to access the first one (based upon your sample data)
- within that you want to loop over the `Occupations` to get the one's you want `occ`
- and you want to display `Name` so reference it via `occ.Name`

*Note: The controller is using `timeout` to mimic the `$http` promise resolution in the plnkr*